# Assign RTF/HTML code to Excel cell

Tags: c#

I am Working on Microsoft C#.net(windows)

I have a requirement ,

I have an excel file containing formatted text in a cell (ex: text will be bold,italic,color) . I need to save the cell content in to the sql database.
  Then i need to show the saved formatted text from database to a new excel file.

How to assign RTF code and HTML code to Excel cell.

Is there any option available. Please help

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use openxml to split the data along with cell formart and save in different tables in your db by referencing some id. 
Lets say sheet 1 has sheetid as 1 and against this sheet id save data in your table and against same sheetid save cell number and style associated like font border fill.

Below Link can be helpful. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellformat.aspx

I am writing code for the same will share soon